# AngularJS promises don't execute in order

Tags: javascript, angularjs, promise

I can’t get my head around some of the promises. They work fine in some instances of my app, but in some they just never work.

In my controller, I have the following command:

```
   myFactory.redrawCategories()
        .then(myFactory.redrawTasks());
```

The redrawTasks function is called instantly, without waiting for the redrawCategories to finish.

The functions inside my factory look like this

```
   redrawTasks: function(){
        var defer = $q.defer();
        db.getAllDocs("task_").then(function(res) {

            angular.forEach(res, function(value){
               value = value.doc;
               tasks[value.category].push(value);
            });

            angular.forEach(tasks, function(taskArray, cat){
                // some code
            });

            defer.resolve(1);

        });

        return defer.promise;

    },
```

The other one is like

```
   redrawCategories: function(){

        var deferred = $q.defer();

        db.getAllDocs("category_").then(function(res) {

                var categoryArray = [];
                angular.forEach(res, function(value){
                    categoryArray.push(value.doc);
                });

                deferred.resolve("done");

        });


        return deferred.promise;

    },
```

Some of the unimortant code has been removed for better overview.

No idea really how to do it. I've tried putting the resolve() function just in front of the return but that doesn't work either.

I've read that sometimes you have to wrap things in a $scope.$apply, well in this case most likely a $rootScope.$apply as it's in the factory outside of the controller scope, but that doesn't really change it either, besides I haven't really grasped when something is "outside of Angular" as they describe that.

I've read a lot of examples and tutorials, but I just don't see the forest for the trees anymore.

Any help would be appreciated a lot. I'm so stuck with this :/ Thanks

Comment: `myFactory.redrawTasks()` -- executes immeditaly and passes the result as callback, whereas `myFactory.redrawTasks` does not call the function but passes its references as the callback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.then` expects a function reference.

```
myFactory.redrawCategories()
    .then(myFactory.redrawTasks());
```

should be

```
myFactory.redrawCategories()
    .then(myFactory.redrawTasks);
```

When you have the `()` the function is executed immediately and `.then` is passed whatever it returned.

As noted in the comments, if you're relying on `this` in `redrawTasks` you'd do

```
myFactory.redrawCategories()
    .then(function() { 
       return myFactory.redrawTasks();
    });
```

Comment: my god, I can't believe it was that simple and I never saw that. Thanks so much for the _very_ quick and simple fix. Day saved :)

Comment: Note that this will fail if `redrawTasks` uses `this`

Comment: Good point. I suppose you'd get around that by doing `.then(function() { myFactory.redrawTasks() })`? I've never had problems with `this` in javascript so I never really spent any calories in understanding how it works.

Comment: Both your solution in the first line and your assertion that follows is correct - especially in the browser JavaScript ecosystem where people dislike this. In NodeJS it's actually pretty common.

Comment: Thanks, I'll add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
myFactory.redrawCategories()
    .then(myFactory.redrawTasks);
```

You were calling the function. Instead you just want to pass it to then function and have angular call it.